# NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using carrier wave and i get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object
```

when i do `u.commentfile = params[:file]`

in the console? help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. In the console, you're not in the scope of a request, so the `params` variable isn't defined unless you've done so manually. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to attach a file when creating a comment, but after i click browse and submit nothing actually gets saved

Comment: Ah, so you were trying to reproduce in the console? Probably not going to work that well. I'd suggest checking your log-file to see if that sheds any light. Once you've narrowed it down, if you still can't solve it, perhaps you can post another question with relevant bits of Model, View and Controller.

Comment: I would suggest writing tests

Comment: I have a old post which is unanswered which has all MVC stuff at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110562/carrierwave-problem-files-not-showing only problem I am having is the file is not saving

Comment: I only vote down because though the questioner was answered, when I come to this question via google the answer has nothing to do with the stated question.